# Was a nascent inverse function theorem known to Newton?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, math-history

More specifically, was Newton aware that given an inverse pair of functions $f$ and $h$ such that

$$f(h(x)) = x = h(f(x))$$ about the origin that, for

$$(x,y)=(h(y),f(x)),$$

the derivatives satisfy

$$f^{'}(x) = 1/h^{'}(y)$$

or

$$dy/dx = 1/(dx/dy)$$

near the origin?

Heuristically, this follows symbolically from

$$dy = f^{'}(x)dx = f^{'}(x)h^{'}(y)dy, $$
or, equivalently, from the chain rule applied to the top equation.

And it follows geometrically for a function whose graph lies in the first quadrant by reflection through the bisector of the first quadrant, the line $y=x$. Clearly, the slope for any tangent line is inverted by the reflection just as displacements along the $x-$axis and the $y-$axis are interchanged. In fact, it follows directly from the tangent line perspective since
 $$ y = m \; x + b$$ and 
 $$y = \frac{1}{m}(x-b)$$ describe an inverse pair.

Surely, with Newton's mastery of geometric calculus, he was aware of these relationships. Is there evidence of this in Newton's work?

Related [MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196058/history-of-frac-ddt-tan-1t-frac-11t2#comment671951_196058) by Ziegler.

Cross-posted from this [MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271568/was-a-nascent-inverse-function-theorem-known-to-newton?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Edit 6/12/17:

An example of a calculation incorporating the IFT that would have been obvious to Newton and plausible for him to have performed if only as a simple check of his general formulas:

It was known well before Newton that

$$\frac{d\tan(x)}{dx} = 1+ \tan^2(x),$$

or, with $y = \tan(x)$,

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1+ y^2.$$

In terms of fluxions and fluents, this could be put in the form of [Newton's implicit function](https://books.google.com/books?id=vLBJSmA9zgAC&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q&f=false)

$$g(x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y})=\dot{y}-(1+y^2)\dot{x}=0.$$

Then

$$\frac{\dot{x}}{\dot{y}}= \frac{1}{1+y^2}=\frac{dx}{dy}, $$

and application of the binomial theorem and integration would give the series

$$
\arctan(y) = x = y - \frac{y^3}3+\frac{y^5}5-\frac{y^7}7+\dots.
\tag3
$$

Newton could then have derived a series expression for $\tan(x)$ using his series reversion formula (see [Ferraro](https://books.google.com/books?id=vLBJSmA9zgAC&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q&f=false)) for finding the series for the compositional inverse of a function from its power series. In fact, the same procedure is applied to finding a series for $\sin(x)$ in Ferraro on pages 76-78 following an alleged reconstruction by Horsley of Newton's derivation of the series.

Edit (Apr 10, 2018):

According to the Wikipedia article on the chain rule, both Newton and Leibniz were aware of the chain rule, and the inverse function theorem in its simplest form follows from application of the chain rule to $x = f(f^{-1}(x))$. This would provide an easy check for the veracity of the chain rule that someone as fastidious as Newton would have used.

Comment: If you're going to x-post, the [hsm.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) is (probably) another good choice.

Comment: Will do if this venue proves unproductive, but MSE has a broader range of users than either MO or HSM.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/documenta/vol-ismp/13_deuflhard-peter.pdf), Newton's original discussion of his namesake method of root finding does not incorporate the derivative concept at all. This would be argument _against_ knowing an inverse function theorem, at least by the time of writing of the Principia.

Comment: Wait, reading your question again, what exactly do you mean by an "inverse function theorem?" (That if a function has non-vanishing derivative it has locally an inverse function? That's my reading of those three words, but maybe you mean something different.)

Comment: I would not bet against it.  I suspect that many "toolbox" lemmas like this one were regarded by Newton as "obvious" and not worth mentioning.

Comment: Would be nice to have some evidence that Newton used the IFT (i.e., reciprocal derivatives) to check his series soln. for implicit functions for particular cases; his series for inverse functions that he did from geometric calculus arguments, e.g., for the sine and asin; or series derived from his series reversion formula. See the Ferraro ref in Ziegler's Q. Turnbull also notes in "Newton: The algebraist and geometer" that Newton wrote to Collins about his series soln. for $a x^p+b x^q = c $, regarded as an inversion problem for $x$ in terms of $y=c$ and parameters $a$ & $b$.

Comment: @WillieWong, the full text spells out what I mean--the reciprocal relation between tangent slopes, i.e., the reciprocal relation of the derivatives for the inverse pair.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, I suspect that also, but Newton, like many consummate theoreticians, tended to check his propositions extensively with particular examples--in one anecdote with five different derivations of the same soln for a problem. Is there an example where he clearly used the reciprocal derivatives to check series expansions for inverses, for example?

Comment: @WillieWong, btw, the geometric reflection method provides an inverse for the graph of $y=0$ as $x=0$ still satisfying the reciprocal derivative relation.

Comment: I am not an authority on the history of Newton. There may be examples.

Comment: Related:  pg. 241 of A History of Mathematics by Cajori, where he briefly notes Newton's method of solving implicit equations in two fluxions and one fluent through simple integration. Also discussed by Ferraro.

Comment: Related: http://www.math.wpi.edu/IQP/BVCalcHist/calc3.html Gregory's series for arctan

Comment: Roy in "The discovery of the series formula for π by Leibnitz, Gregory, and Nilakantha" states in Section 3 that Gregory derived series for the tan, arctan, sec, arcsec, and various logs in an unsuccessful attempt to reproduce a method of Newton that Roy says, "consisted of reversion of series, expansion by the binomial theorem, long division by series, and term by term integration."

Answer (score 1):

In a certain sense it is *obvious* that Newton knew this at least after 1684, since Leibniz published his foundational article on infinitesimal calculus that year.  In that article Leibniz introduces the notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ (the quotient of infinitesimal differentials) and from this point of view your observation is obvious.  The mathematicians in England may have been late in adopting Leibnizian notation but Newton was surely aware of the scientific developments on the continent.

Comment: The notation of Leibnitz is suggestive, but makes the gist of the IFT no more obvious, and in my opinion less obvious, than the fluxion notation, which doesn't denote a ratio of differentials but rather a ratio of two derivatives w.r.t. a shared parameter, a ratio that is equivalent to the desired derivative, a ratio that naturally has a reciprocal since it is a ratio of numbers, or evaluated functions, not pure differentials. The prime notation gives the more precise interpretation of the IFT. (Btw, Needham gives another graphical interpretation of the IFT, couched in complex analysis.)

Comment: In other words, the formula in the Leibnitz notation is really an abuse of notation--the prime notation being the more accurate and directly related to the implicit function formulation of Newton, denoted as $f (x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y})=0$ by Ferraro, and its Newton transform $\frac{\dot {y}}{\dot{x}}=g(x,y)$, which puts the two fluxions on an equal footing and therefore gives an obvious, precise interpretation of reciprocal of the ratio of the fluxions as $1/g(x,y)=\frac{\dot {x}}{\dot{y}}$.

Comment: Tom, your question wasn't concerned with rigor but rather with the question of Newton's awareness of such a formula.

Comment: My questioni is stated more precisely in the body of the question than in the title, naturally. After explaining what I mean by a nascent IFT (anticipating such a reaction as Wong's, who apparently didn't read my explanation), I ask, "Is there evidence of this in Newton's WORK?" You say he could have surmised it just from Leibniz's notation, but that is not Newton's work. Further, my comments to your answer really amount  to saying that the naive formulation from Leibniz notation is specious (a non sequitar), or at best ambiguous.

Comment: Certainly in the applications of the IFT in my writtings I must think in terms of the formula in the prime notation, with careful definitions of the argumens of the inverse pair of functions, to accurately apply the IFT.